# Import multiple selected json files from the file directory, using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, import

I have 23000+ json files in the folder.

For testing purposes, I would like to read only 10 files.

```
# Read several files
file1 = 'tweets201706221015.json'
file2 = 'tweets201706221115.json'
file3 = 'tweets201706221215.json'
file4 = 'tweets201706221315.json'
file5 = 'tweets201706221415.json'
file6 = 'tweets201706221515.json'
file7 = 'tweets201706221615.json'
file8 = 'tweets201706221715.json'
file9 = 'tweets201706221815.json'
file10 = 'tweets201706221915.json'
```

**Or even only better - randomly selected 10 json files.**

I found this answer, but it just reads `json` files from the folder, this is not a problem for me. I want just a small sample of data.

My code:

```
directory = some directory
files = [file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6, file7, file8, file9, file10]

path = directory + files
```

Comment: What's your exact problem? You didn't include any approach or code - have you tried iterating over your files and reading each fiel individually?

Comment: I tried to create a list of files `files = [file1, file2, file3, file4, file5, file6, file7, file8, file9, file10]`, and then read as `path = directory + files`, but it is not that simple. Thanks!

Comment: It's exactly that simple! Please update your question with the code or else we have a hard time debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment section above, just establish a normal list and iterate over each filename, e.g.:

```
#For simplicity reasons just three files - you can use a generator or read the filenames from the directory
files = ['file1.json', 'file2.json', 'file3.json']

for file in files:
   f = open(file)
   #Do your stuff with the file
   f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Simply use a for loop to get files to name and then read each file.

for i in range (10):
    filename = "tweets201706221%s15.json" % i

    for line in open(filename, 'r'):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

First Use os.listdir()  to get list of all JSON files from the directory then Select 10 files randomly from that list. Then finally you can loop over those 10 files to load using normal open function.

This should help to to select randomly
[www.geeksforgeeks.org/randomly-select-n-elements-from-list-in-python/amp/](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/randomly-select-n-elements-from-list-in-python/amp/)

Answer (score 1):

For random picks from directory,

```
import os
import random 

# pick ten files from the /json/dir directory
ten_files = random.choices(os.listdir('/json/dir'), k=10)

for fi in ten_files:
    with open(f'/json/dir/{fi}') as in_file:
        # do something with in_file
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for your time!